# Kotlin close fragment onclick

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fragment that is called from the activity_main screen when a main menu drop down option is clicked. I am trying to have the fragment close and show the activity_main screen again when the cancel button is clicked. I have user input in the activity_main screen that I would like to still be there if the fragment is closed while clicking cancel but at this point i will settle for the fragment just closing and the activity_main showing back at it's original state.

I am using androidx and all of the answers I have found so far have been compatible with android.support.v7

This is the code that i have in my fragment, it does not do anything at all when I click the 'Cancel' button, the fragment just continues to sit there over the activity_main.

```
class SaveFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.savefragment, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        b_cancel.setOnClickListener {
            fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that calls the savefragment from the MainActivity:

```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.i_save -> {
                val SaveFragment = SaveFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main_main, SaveFragment).commit()
                true
            }
            R.id.i_recall -> {
                val RecallFragment = RecallFragment()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main_main, RecallFragment).commit()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Any help at all in Kotlin would be appreciated.

Comment: You can instead do `if(view == b_cancel) { /* Logic here with view */ }`. Try using findViewById & android.R.id attributes, instead of kotlin synthetics, they usually don't work.

Comment: Please include the code that shows SaveFragment from activity_main.

Comment: @shinwan updated

Comment: @ClarkeWoogner your code for showing the fragment does not use `addToBackStack` that `popBackStack` requires. You can either try to add it  (`replace(…).addToBackStack(…).commit()`) or avoid using `popBackStack` when removing SaveFragment (`fragmentManager?.beginTransaction().remove(this@SaveFragment).commit()`).

Comment: @shinwan that worked perfectly, thank you!